# How would I complete this problem in less time?

Tags: javascript, big-o

EDIT: So I changed my code to the following:

```
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
    let pairs = 0;
    let arr = [];
    b.reverse()
    for (num in a) {
        result = String(a[num]) + String(b[num])
        if (result < k) {
            pairs++
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```

It works the exact same, without needing to check new arr/push, etc. Would this run in less time? Is there a way to check myself how long it takes?

I was doing a Codesignal javascript practice test (now finished). I had a really hard time, and now know that I need a lot more practice before I can even think of doing the actual test. One of the questions was:

"You are given two arrays of integers a and b of the same length, and an integer k. We will be iterating through array a from left to right, and simultaneously through array b from right to left, and looking at pairs (x, y), where x is from a and y is from b. Such a pair is called tiny if the concatenation xy is strictly less than k."

This was the code that I wrote:

```
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
    let pairs = 0;
    let arr = [];
    b.reverse()
    for (num in a) {
        for (num in b) {
            result = String(a[num]) + String(b[num])
            if (result < k) {
                if ((arr.findIndex(e => e === result)) === -1) {
                    arr.push(String(result));
                    pairs++
                }        
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```

It works, except execution time limit is 4 seconds. There is a hidden test case where my function takes longer than 4 seconds to complete (I'm assuming the arrays have an extreme amount of numbers). I haven't learned anything about the Big O (or whatever it's called) yet, so I have no clue on anything about it.

I'm guessing I'd have to learn about it before I could successfully solve this problem on my own? Or, did I just write bad code and it's possible to do it with better code without knowing a thing about Big O?

Comment: `for (num in a)` followed by `for (num in b)` are both using the same implicit global. Are you *sure* this works?

Comment: Say the length is 3, you're testing (x1,y3), (x1,y2), (x1,y1), (x2,y3), (x2,y2), (x2,y1), (x3,y3), (x3,y2), (x3,y1). The way I understand the exercise, is that you're supposed to test only (x1,y3), (x2,y2), (x3,y1), which would need a single `for` loop, from 0 to length-1. This would move from O(n*n) to O(n). Yet, "and simultaneously through array b" isn't very clear, I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is bad code, you don't have to learn anything about Big O to be able to solve problems efficiently.

Comment: Also, [don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/8376184)

Comment: @FZs What's wrong with for..in? Oh...it's supposed to be for of, right? I first learned js, then went to python, and now back to js. It's confusing :/

Comment: @Cat `for..in` is bad for arrays only (explained in the link). For arrays, use `for..of`, or if you need the index, a regular `for`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't include the full description.  What are you supposed to return, the number of concatenated values that are less than the target or the number of indices that yield such a concatenated value?  For instance in `countTinyPairs([2, 9, 2], [5, 3, 5], 30)`, we check [25, 93, 25]` to see if each is less than 30.  Do we return `1`, because `25` is the only value that matches or `2` because  `25` is in there twice?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I can't go back to access the full question, but I copied/pasted everything except the examples. From what I remember, it never said anything about duplicates, so I have no clue. In my original code, I only checked for duplicates as it looped over each output the length of loop times, which I now understand was a bad way to go about it

Comment: @Cat, at a guess, then, the whole duplicate checking might be unnecessary.

Comment: I feel like there's even a solution in O(n/2), where each iteration would test two pairs... Easier with an even number of elements.

Comment: @sp00m no, that's not `n/2`. You *can* iterate to half the length of `a` and take two pairs at a time - front of `a` with back of `b` and vice versa until you reach the middle. However, that's *not* half of `n` - you've halved the amount of iterations but doubled the amount of elements you visit. So you still visit `n` elements. Besides, we drop constants for big-O notation. Manually expanding the loop this way *used to* sometimes lead to better performance in the past. However, most compiler will implement [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) making it unnecessary.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, interesting, I need to read more about Big-O to be honest. I thought it was more about the number of iterations (n/2) than the number of elements being visited (n), as a lookup by index is a constant-time operation if I'm not wrong. But I didn't know about _loop unrolling_ either, so yeah, thanks for having commented back :)

Comment: @sp00m big-O is a bit of a rough estimate of how much work an algorithm does. It doesn't really go into too much specifics as we are only interested in how an algorithm generally behaves. *Usually*, `O(n)` means there is a linear relation - if you double the input, you'd double the runtime of the algorithm. In reality, that's not always the case - most algorithms might be something like `n + 10` - a loop with some fixed cost that's always done (the 10) like fetching the elements to loop through. However, to compare algorithms easier, we drop constants and just focus on the largest exponent

Comment: @sp00m for `n`. We generally have `O(1)` (constant time, regardless of input), `O(log n)` (logarithmic, e.g., binary search), `O(n)` (e.g., single loop), `O(n * log n)` (log linear. Common for sorting algorithms), `O(n^2)` (quadratic - e,g, two nested loops), `O(2^n)` (exponential. Bad) `O(n!)` (factorial. Worse). From time complexity perspective, it's the same whether you loop through all elements once or twice `O(2n) = O(n)`. Also, remember that it's just an estimate of the work. You can have `O(1)` algorithm that takes a week for any input. Constant time but nested loop might be faster.

Comment: @VLAZ brilliant, thank you! You should write all this in a blog post ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no need for multiple loops. You have *three*:

- `b.reverse()` will reverse `b` in-place with likely `O(n)` complexity. Even if it's `O(log n)` it's still unnecessary.
- `for (num in a)` iterates over `a` in `O(n)`.
- `for (num in b)` iterates over `b` in `O(n)`. However, since it's an inner loop, the total is `O(n^2)`.
- `arr.findIndex(e => e === result)` will trigger another `O(m)` iteration over any pair found. Depending on the value of `k` that might be only a few times or many. It's *already* in an `O(n^2)`, so worst case scenario is a high value of `k` that covers every combination of pairs, so it will be triggered every time and thus you would get a `O(n^3)` complexity.

### Eliminate multiple loops over `a` and `b`

Given that both `a` and `b` are of equal length, we can trivially iterate over both arrays with a single loop. To achieve reverse iteration, we can employ basic arithmetic to get the index for `b` that has the same distance from the end as the index of `a` has from the beginning. Or in other words, you can do this to iterate over both arrays at once in two directions:

```js
const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  const j = b.length - i - 1; //reverse the index for `b`
  
  console.log(`${a[i]}, ${b[j]}`);
}
```

Note that `a.length` and `b.length` are interchangeable, as the problem description says they are identical.

#### Drop the constant lookups in `arr`

The next problem is that `arr` is repeatedly being iterated over *only* to check the existence of a pair. Instead you can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Lookups and inserts will have sub-linear complexity by specs. Many implementations can even give you `O(1)`. You can simplify your code to

```
const pairs = new Set();

/* ... if a pair is found ... */
pairs.add(result);

/* ... produce count ... */
return pairs.size;
```

### Summary

The complete solution can look like this and you only need to iterate once through both `a` and `b` at the same time:

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = new Set();

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const j = b.length - i - 1;
    const pair = `${a[i]}${b[j]}`;
    
    if (Number(pair) < k) {
      pairs.add(pair);
    }
  }
  
  return pairs.size;
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

### Alternative

This can also be expressed using array methods leading to shorter code at the cost of two loops with `.map` and `.filter`, then a third to convert to a `Set`:

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = a
    .map((x, index) => `${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`) //produce pair
    .filter(x => Number(x) < k); //leave only tiny ones
    
  return new Set(pairs).size; //deduplicate and count
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

Using `.reduce` to bring it down to one loop again:

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = a
    .reduce((acc, x, index) => {
      const pair = `${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`;
      if (Number(pair) < k) {
        return acc.add(pair);
      }
      return acc;
    }, new Set());
    
  return pairs.size; //deduplicate and count
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

Finally, if you hate yourself you can very make it into a single expression:

```js
const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) => 
  a.reduce(
    (acc, x, index) => 
      (pair => (Number(pair) < k) ? acc.add(pair) : acc)
        (`${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`), 
    new Set()).size;

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

### No discarding of duplicates

If there is no need to remove duplicates, then the whole code becomes even simpler - you only need to maintain a count, not even collect the pairs:

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const j = b.length - i - 1;
    const pair = `${a[i]}${b[j]}`;
    
    if (Number(pair) < k) {
      pairs++;
    }
  }
  
  return pairs;
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

Or using array methods:

#### `.map()` + `.filter()`

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = a
    .map((x, index) => `${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`) //produce pair
    .filter(x => Number(x) < k); //leave only tiny ones
    
  return pairs.length;
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

#### `.reduce()`

```js
function countTinyPairs(a, b, k) {
  let pairs = a
    .reduce((count, x, index) => {
      const pair = `${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`;
      if (Number(pair) < k) {
        return count + 1;
      }
      return count;
    }, 0);
    
  return pairs;
}

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

#### Single expression `.reduce()`

```js
const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) => 
  a.reduce(
    (count, x, index) => 
      count + (Number(`${x}${b[b.length - index - 1]}`) < k), 
    0);

const a = [2, 9, 2];
const b = [5, 3, 5];

console.log(countTinyPairs(a, b, 30));
```

Answer (score 2):

The wording of the question is somewhat ambiguous and it doesn't help that a concrete input and expected output have not been provided. Here's how I would write the solution based on my understanding of the question -

```
const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) =>
  loop
    ( ( [ x, xs ] = likeList(a)
      , [ y, ys ] = likeList([...b].reverse())
      , pairs = 0
      ) =>
      x == null || y == null
        ? pairs
        : recur
            ( xs
            , ys
            , Number(`${x}${y}`) < k
                ? pairs + 1
                : pairs
            )
    )
```

```js
console.log(countTinyPairs([1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6,7], 40))
// => 3
```

Using our own generic functions, `loop`, `recur`, and `likeList`, we can dramatically reduce the conceptual overhead required to derive the answer -

```js
const likeList = (t = [], c = 0) =>
  ({ [Symbol.iterator]: _ => [ t[c], likeList(t, c + 1) ].values() })
  
const recur = (...v) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => v.values() })
  
const loop = (f, ...init) =>
{ let r = f(...init)
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = f(...r)
  return r
}
```

If you'd like to learn more about the design choices for these helpers, I encourage you to see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64144064/633183).

Expand the snippet below to run the program and verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const likeList = (t = [], c = 0) =>
  ({ [Symbol.iterator]: _ => [ t[c], likeList(t, c + 1) ].values() })
  

const recur = (...v) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => v.values() })
  
const loop = (f, ...init) =>
{ let r = f(...init)
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = f(...r)
  return r
}

const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) =>
  loop
    ( ( [ x, xs ] = likeList(a)
      , [ y, ys ] = likeList([...b].reverse())
      , pairs = 0
      ) =>
      x == null || y == null
        ? pairs
        : recur
            ( xs
            , ys
            , Number(`${x}${y}`) < k
                ? pairs + 1
                : pairs
            )
    )
  
console.log(countTinyPairs([1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6,7], 40))
// 3
```

---

There's room for an optimisation here. Here we introduce `likeReversedList` -

```js
const likeReversedList = (t = [], c = 0) =>
  ({ [Symbol.iterator]: _ => [ t[t.length - c - 1], likeReversedList(t, c + 1) ].values() })
```

```
const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) =>
  loop
    ( ( [ x, xs ] = likeList(a)
      , [ y, ys ] = likeList([...b].reverse())
      , [ y, ys ] = likeReversedList(b) // <-
      , pairs = 0
      ) =>
      // ...
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`You are given two arrays of integers a and b of the same length`. The length is the same so we need to iterate only once improving it from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`. You still need to check every element, so that is the best possible complexity for this problem.

The if statement checking for duplicates is as unneeded as the variable `pairs`.
You can use a `Set` that will check for duplicates and in the end, return its `length` instead of counting the pairs manually.

I'm attaching the examplary solution below:

```js
const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) => {
        const set = new Set();
        for (let i = 0, j = b.length-1; i < a.length; i++, j--) {
                const result = String(a[i]) + String(b[j])
                if (result < k) {
                    set.add(result);
                }
        }
        return set.size;
    }

    console.log(countTinyPairs([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], 40))
```

**Edit** it is not necessary to have a separate variable called `j`, but I thought it wad more readable having in stored in a variable.

If we don't need to check for duplicates, then it's enough to write it like this:

```
   const countTinyPairs = (a, b, k) => {
        let pairs;
        for (let i = 0, j = b.length-1; i < a.length; i++, j--) {
                if (String(a[i]) + String(b[j])< k) pairs++
        }
        return pairs;
    }
```

Comment: I edited my post right before I saw this answer (which is kinda the same as my edited code). So if I had originally written this, would it have worked within the 4 second time limit? Is there a way I can test time run myself?

Comment: in your edited code, there is still an unnecessary part  `b.reverse()` which takes `O(n)`. When it comes to checking how long does it take, there is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163507/is-there-a-way-i-can-check-how-long-it-takes-for-javascript-to-execute-a-functio) how to do it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's true, but by looking at the example before edit I thought it's necessary to check for duplicates.

Comment: @Cat please, edit the description to clarify whether it's needed.

Comment: It didn't say anything about duplicates, so to be honest, I have no idea.

Comment: Your code is testing for duplicates, and that may be leading others astray.  Your description ends with "Such a pair is called tiny if the concatenation xy is strictly less than k."  Does it then explain what you're supposed to return?  Is the the tiny pairs, and if so, in what format?  Is it the count of all tiny pairs found?  Is it the count of the unique tiny pairs found?  We're missing a requirement.

Comment: I believe "the count of all tiny pairs found". Which means, if there was a test that had duplicates, my original code would fail. I wonder why none of the tests had duplicates? Unless it was after the really long test, and it just never ran because it stopped after hitting longer than 4 seconds.

Comment: You asked about finding the run-time of your function.  You can use [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [timeEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd) to log the running time of a function.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of your code is O(n^2)

Here is how I would solve it. I hope I got the task right, please post some examples of input/output.

1. If a and b are of equal length you can iterate through them with a single loop. The complexity would be O(n) where n is the length of a.
2. Why check for duplicates? Is that a requirement?

   ```
   function test(a,b,k)
   {
     let x,y,i,xy, result =[];
     for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     {
        x = a[i];
        y = b[b.length - 1 -i]
        xy = parseInt([x,y].join(''));
        if (xy < k) result.push(xy);
     }
     return result;
    }
    let a = [1,2,3,4,5], b=[4,5,6,7,8], k = 40;
    console.log(test(a,b,k));

    // Output: [18, 27, 36]
   ```